How should I handle the value function when the environment is rested in a truncated case?
I read the document of Terminated / Truncated and understood the difference between terminated case and truncated case of the environment, but I can not understand why the value is updated like below.
If terminated:  # case 1
    Next q-value = reward
Else:  # case 2
    Next q-value = reward + discount factor * max action of the Q (next state, action)

# This can more efficiently be written
Next q-value = reward + (not terminated) * discount factor * max action of the Q(next state, action)

As I understand, the environment will be reset after the truncated signal, and the next step is the initial step of the environment, which is called from env.reset(). There is no relation between the state and the next state in this case, and I don't know why the value is updated using Q value of the next state.
Let's assume the time limit of the environment is 1000. Then, whatever the state of the 1000th step is, the next step will be the initial step of the environment. Even in the same state and same action, if the time step is not 1000, the next state will be different and different Q value will be used.
Why the Q term of the next state is used for updating the value in the truncated case? Isn't it better to ignore the Q term in the truncated case also?
Also, I wonder how to handle the Q term of the next state in continuing tasks. Will the wrong state (which is called from env.reset()) be considered the next state in every truncated case?
I tried to find similar questions but couldn't find any. There may be some reasons, but I can find out why.
